# need a solution for scheduled email messages

Tags: email, scheduled-tasks

I have developed a certain system (with Classic ASP and MSSSQL 2012) for managing customer files for an insurance company.

Among other features, the system should be able to let the user set an automatic email message to be sent out to a defined email address at specific date and time.

After trying to achieve this goal with the native service of Scheduled Tasks on the server, and finding it very unreliable, I am looking now for an external service.

The "holy grail" for me will be to find a service much like FollowUpThen, which provides the option to send an email message at a specific date and time in a very simple way.

The problem with their service is that you cannot define the email addresses where the message will be sent to, so that's a "game killer" for me, unfortunately.

So, basically I am currently looking for a service that will allow me (programmaticaly) to send out scheduled email messages.

Any kind of help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The formatting of your question is horrible^^

Comment: You're right. :) I've been writing this question in a period of 2 hours, on and off, and then didn't have the time to review it... :) Better now?...

Comment: Lol...no, in fact I was talking about the usage of line breaks ;)

Comment: So basically, YOUR comment was horribly formatted...  :) :)

Comment: You could check out Mailgun; they have a quite simple api and you can schedule email delivery: http://blog.mailgun.com/tips-tricks-scheduling-email-delivery/

Answer (score 0):

Iterable.com supports scheduling an email for delivery up to 365 days in the future. See https://api.iterable.com/api/docs#!/email/target_post_0

Please note that the content of the email is set at the time you schedule it, not on the scheduled delivery date.